# Why Fira Code in VS Code lost after restart PC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, settings

I want to use Fira Code in VS Code to enable the Font Ligatures. This is my settings in settings.json. Note that I already installed Fira Code in C:\Windows\Font

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
```

My VS Code change the font to Fira Code and I can use Font Ligatures. However, after every time I restart my laptop, then the Fira Code in VS Code is gone. I need to copy Fira Code font to C:\Windows\Font to enable Fira Code again in VS Code.

Is there anyone have this issue? How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same problem and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/issues/137#issuecomment-550973296) solution worked for me.

- Make sure to unblock all the font files in their properties (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB0Vh.png))
- Install Fira Code fonts by clicking on *Install for all users* option instead of *Install* (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovn91.png)).