# Fonts not working in VS code after a restart

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

My VS code font changes to default every time I open up my PC. I need to reinstall the font to use it in VS code. The font works in other apps though. I think there's something wrong with my VS code but I can't figure it out.

**Font works when**

- I reinstall the font.
- Once it works, closing/opening the app doesn't reset the font.
- Default fonts like courier, consolas always work.

**Font doesn't work when**

- I restart my PC.

Comment: I have followed instructions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917339/why-fira-code-in-vs-code-lost-after-restart-pc